# Xcode9 Duplicate Line Shortcut

Tags: xcode, configuration, plist, shortcut, xcode9

How do I add a shortcut in Xcode 9 to duplicate lines?
I've seen people suggest to edit IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist , but I can't find this file anywhere.
(Also I'm not very proficient on mac os yet)